# При перезагрузке страницы сворачивается select

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Вот так выглядит мой селектор по умолчанию:
[image]
Вот так при выборе какого-либо option:
[image]
Я сделал так, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы запоминался бы выбранный option, но в итоге выводится только сам option без форм внутри него:
[image]
Вот скрипты, думаю где-то здесь может быть ошибка:

```
 <!-- Save selector -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    var $select = $('#productType');

    function handleSelectValue() {
        var selectedClass = $select.find(':selected').data('class');
        localStorage.setItem("selected", selectedClass);
    }

    var cookie = localStorage.getItem("selected");
    if (cookie) {
        $select.find('[data-class="' + cookie + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }

    handleSelectValue();

    $select.on('change', handleSelectValue);
    });
    </script>   
    <!-- Option's hide/show -->
    <script>
        $('#productType').change(function(){
        if($('#productType option:selected').filter('#dvdDisc').length) {
        $("#dvdSizes").show();
        $("#bookSizes").hide();
        $("#furnitureSizes").hide();
            }
        else if($('#productType option:selected').filter('#book').length) {
            $("#dvdSizes").hide();
            $("#bookSizes").show();
            $("#furnitureSizes").hide();
        }
        else if($('#productType option:selected').filter('#furniture').length) {
            $("#dvdSizes").hide();
            $("#bookSizes").hide();
            $("#furnitureSizes").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#dvdSizes").hide();
            $("#bookSizes").hide();
            $("#furnitureSizes").hide();
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Буду благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте повешать тригер на селект после изменения значения

```
if (cookie) {
    $select.find('[data-class="' + cookie + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $select.trigger('change');
}
```